# How to implement loading bar for apis in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a status bar something like in this : https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/using-web-components

[image]
This should be called when a user hits an api.

I tried with https://ant.design/components/progress/#header , by continuously changing the progress every 100ms, but how to exactly make it look continuous as in https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/using-web-components

```
    useEffect(()=>{
    if(loading==true){
        setPercent(0)
       changePercent()
    }
  },[loading])
  const changePercent=()=>{
      if(loading==false){
          return
      }
      if(loadingPercent<99){
        const rotation = loadingPercent + 1;
        setPercent(rotation)
      
      }else{
          setPercent(0)
      }
      requestAnimationFrame(changePercent);
  }
```

It's showing the progress 1 , and the functions is not being called again

Comment: Oh god, I just opened the network tab on their site. They're downloading every class definition in a separate request.

Comment: haha, just realized

Answer (score 2):

If you're faking the progress just so the user has something to look at, I think you'll get the smoothest results by using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout` and using the time since start of the animation to calculate the current "progress"

Comment: have added the code I'm using with antD progress, can you once check

Comment: Does that work for you? I'd expect it would throw an error for the self-reference in `changePercent`, maybe define it as a regular `function` instead. Note, that function will currently make the progress bar loop, rather than slow down approaching 100% like some pages do it.